# How to make a Http call before Alexa Skill.launch and change the Invocation speech based on the response received in Node JS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Below is my issue:

- need to make http call and get the repsonse
- process the response   and get the required value
- Now based on the value received above change the invocation of Launch.

Issue is:

If I define a global variable it is executed first due to asyn and speech gets changed, if I use promise function inside skill function I am not able to invoke anything.

How to resolve this.

Below is my code (Please note this is not all the code)

Hi I am trying to change the greeting note after invocation based on a API response. But when I call the wakeup word Alexa just blinks and stops.

```
'use strict';
module.change_code = 1;
var Alexa = require('alexa-app');
var skill = new Alexa.app('greeter-service');

var Patientdata = function (callback){
var body = [] ;
const https = require('http');
https.get('SomeURL', (resp) => {
resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
body.push(chunk);
});
resp.on('end', () => {
body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
let  jbody = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(jbody);
callback(jbody);
});
});
};

function Checkdata(cb)
{
  Patientdata(function(res){

console.log(res);
// do some logic
cb(true);

});
}


skill.launch(function(req, res) {

Checkdata(function(def){

if(def)
{
 var prompt = 'Hi Greetings !!! '
    res.say(prompt).reprompt(prompt).shouldEndSession(false);
}
else
{
    var prompt = 'Hi you are not a registered user !!!'
    res.say(prompt).reprompt(prompt).shouldEndSession(false);
}
});
});
```

Comment: Can you please add some more info regarding the efforts you have made already ?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Hi Vebbie and Goncalo, I am new to Node and Alexa. I have tried some ways but was not able to get it work. I have attached a code in question which is one way I tried. Can you help?